# How to Razorpay generate orderId using firebase call function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I have tried this but getting err is not null

```
 const instance = new Razorpay({
      key_id: "myKey",
      key_secret: "mySecret"
    });
     
    exports.generateOrder = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
        
         const options = {
          amount: data.amount,
          currency: "INR",
          receipt: "recipt by me"  //req.body.receipt
        };
        
        instance.orders.create(options, (err, order) => {
            if(err !==  null){
                console.log("ORDERID null");
                return null;
            }else{
                console.log("ORDERID "+order);
                return order;
            }
        });
        
    
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of error in your question ?

Comment: I am not getting the orderId. Console is not showing anything

Comment: If you `console.log(err)` it should log the error.

Comment: Now I am getting console as :ORDERID [object Object]. How to retrieve the orderId from this object?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be error?  Try `console.log("ORDERID "+ JSON.stringify(order));`

Comment: The response is like this  {
  "id": "order_EKwxwAgItmmXdp",
  "entity": "order",
  "amount": 50000,
  "amount_paid": 0,
  "amount_due": 50000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "receipt": "receipt#1",
  "offer_id": null,
  "status": "created",
  "attempts": 0,
  "notes": [],
  "created_at": 1582628071
} How to get the id.

Comment: This is the official page : https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/#step-3-create-an-order-in-your-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of any error, you should log `err` and check that. However if the order is created you can simply return the orderId as shown below:

```
exports.generateOrder = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {        
  const options = {
    amount: data.amount,
    currency: "INR",
    receipt: "recipt by me"  //req.body.receipt
  };        
  return createOrder(options).then((orderId) => {
    return { orderId }
  }).catch(e => {
    return { error: e }
  })  
});


function createOrder(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance.orders.create(options, (err, order) => {
      if(err !==  null){
        console.log("failed to create order", err);
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("ORDERID "+order.id);
        return resolve(order.id);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");


const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

var key_id = "your_key_id";
var key_secret = "your_key_secret";

var instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: 'your_key_id', key_secret: 'your_key_secret' })

exports.createOrderID = functions.https.onCall((data_val, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    instance.orders.create({
      
      amount: data_val.amt,
      currency: "INR",
      receipt: data_val.receipt,
    },function (err,data)
    {
      if (err) {
          reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An unexpected error', err));
          return;
        }
        resolve(data);
    })
  });
  
});
```